# Bermudez C Chapter 5 P 2: No use of arrays or loops for ascending order

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Going through Bermudez's C Programming Tutorial (supplement to KN King's book), and perplexed by the second question of Chapter 5 (Selection Statements).

The problem is as follows: write a program that will read in five values and write them out in ascending order.

The very budding programmer is not allowed to use arrays or loops. The only available tools are "if" and "switch" statements.

Here is my issue: I solved the problem by brute force--it's super inelegant. One guess is that I am supposed to feel upset about this exercise; that is, maybe Bermudez wants to show the reader that one needs to do 5! permutations when solely relying on "if" and/or "switch" statements.

Another guess (and probably the more likely one) is that I am doing something really wrong. Something tells me I can cut this code at least in half.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it is supposed to be a tricky exercise to write loops and arrays substitutions with just `if` and `switch` (which is totally possible)? Does this question even have an answer or commentary of some kind? Maybe you should switch to different book or just do some programming closer to real-world problems? For some reason so many programming books miserably fail to supply good code samples and/or exercises even when the rest of the content is rather helpful.

Comment: Yah no clue. Unfortunately no answer or hint to this problem, and in general, no answers to any of the problems (kind of funny for a supplement). Any recommendations (e.g. books/coding sites) as to where I can do some programming closer to real-world?

Comment: This is the sort of question that is probably best skipped.  I don't see much useful coming out of the answer — it's nasty to sort data unless you can use arrays or linked lists, and functions are normally part of the work too.  When an exercise sets up arbitrary constraints that don't model 'real world' programming, they are seldom all that helpful.  If there are many such questions, maybe the book as a whole should be jettisoned.

Comment: Agreed. The problem book, however, has been pretty helpful here and there. And there is certainly a big positive to come from this exercise: the fact that I went through this laborious exercise and came out unhappy with my inelegant answer led to great responses--all of which have been really illuminating!

Comment: Maybe illuminating, but of no use to future SO visistors/users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be really cheating but it can be done with a tiny bit of code in a [Sorting Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, temp;

    printf("Program 5.2: Ascending Order of Values\n");
    printf("======================================\n\n");

    printf("Enter first value: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Enter second value: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("Enter third value: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    printf("Enter fourth value: ");
    scanf("%d", &d);

    printf("Enter fifth value: ");
    scanf("%d", &e);

    printf("\nRe-arranged in ascending order: \n");
    printf("===============================\n\n");

    /* Sorting Network - 9 comparators */
    if (a > b) { temp = a; a = b; b = temp; } // 0,1
    if (d > e) { temp = d; d = e; e = temp; } // 3,4
    if (c > e) { temp = c; c = e; e = temp; } // 2,4
    if (c > d) { temp = c; c = d; d = temp; } // 2,3
    if (a > d) { temp = a; a = d; d = temp; } // 0,3
    if (a > c) { temp = a; a = c; c = temp; } // 0,2
    if (b > e) { temp = b; b = e; e = temp; } // 1,4
    if (b > d) { temp = b; b = d; d = temp; } // 1,3
    if (b > c) { temp = b; b = c; c = temp; } // 1,2

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/dn4fw9)

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have an algorithm, but it cheats with recursion.

it uses `O(n)` stack, and `O(n^2)` time complexity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool sorted;

void sort(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    if (sorted) return;
    if (a <= b && b <= c && c <= d && d <= e) {
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e);
        sorted = true;
    } else {
        if (a > b) sort(b, a, c, d, e);
        if (b > c) sort(a, c, b, d, e);
        if (c > d) sort(a, b, d, c, e);
        if (d > e) sort(a, b, c, e, d);
    }
}

int main() {
    sorted = false;
    sort(5, 4, 2, 3, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

About the BF algorithm, maybe comparing 2 numbers a time may lead to some simplicity. Many algorithms lead to a tree traversal, there are many factors about the efficiency, like pruning, branch-choosing, etc.

---

UPD

So, for this very problem, there're total `5!=120` situations. So 120 `if else` could have solve it...

```
if (a <= b && b <= c && c <= d && d <= e)...
else (b <= a && b <= c && c <= d && d <= e)...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Should clarify: no use of functions or header files other than stdio.h.

Comment: You would reject ths answer for using stdbool.h?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is not as elegant as @Blastfurnace's but I thought you should just compare each element to everyone else, and decide it's final location using that compare (kinda like quicksort). It's still a fair amount of code, but I think it's easier to understand and simpler...

**Time complexity:** n*(n-1) [count] + n^2 [switch] == 2*(n^2) - n < n! [for big numbers (such as 5 :) )]
**space comlexity:** n [initial variables] + n[count] + n[first,second...] = 3n

```
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    scanf("%d",&c);
    scanf("%d",&d);
    scanf("%d",&e);

    int a_count = 0;
    int b_count = 0;
    int c_count = 0;
    int d_count = 0;
    int e_count = 0;
    int first,second,third,fourth,fifth;

    if(a>b)
        ++a_count;
    if(a>c)
        ++a_count;
    if(a>d)
        ++a_count;
    if(a>e)
        ++a_count;

    if(b>a)
        ++b_count;
    if(b>c)
        ++b_count;
    if(b>d)
        ++b_count;
    if(b>e)
        ++b_count;

    if(c>a)
        ++c_count;
    if(c>b)
        ++c_count;
    if(c>d)
        ++c_count;
    if(c>e)
        ++c_count;

    if (d>a)
        ++d_count;
    if (d>b)
        ++d_count;
    if (d>c)
        ++d_count;
    if (d>e)
        ++d_count;

    if (e>a)
        ++e_count;
    if (e>b)
        ++e_count;
    if (e>c)
        ++e_count;
    if (e>d)
        ++e_count;
    switch(a_count){
        case 0:
            first = a;
            break;
        case 1:
            second = a;
            break;  
        case 2:
            third = a;
            break;
        case 3:
            fourth = a;
            break;
        case 4:
            fifth = a;
            break;              
    }

    switch(b_count){
        case 0:
            first = b;
            break;
        case 1:
            second = b;
            break;  
        case 2:
            third = b;
            break;
        case 3:
            fourth = b;
            break;
        case 4:
            fifth = b;
            break;              
    }   

    switch(c_count){
        case 0:
            first = c;
            break;
        case 1:
            second = c;
            break;  
        case 2:
            third = c;
            break;
        case 3:
            fourth = c;
            break;
        case 4:
            fifth = c;
            break;              
    }

    switch(d_count){
        case 0:
            first = d;
            break;
        case 1:
            second = d;
            break;  
        case 2:
            third = d;
            break;
        case 3:
            fourth = d;
            break;
        case 4:
            fifth = d;
            break;              
    }       

    switch(e_count){
        case 0:
            first = e;
            break;
        case 1:
            second = e;
            break;  
        case 2:
            third = e;
            break;
        case 3:
            fourth = e;
            break;
        case 4:
            fifth = e;
            break;              
    }   

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", first,second,third,fourth,fifth);
    return 0;
}
```

One last thing: every solution here will not be as simple and elegant as using a simple loop. I do think Bermudez intended to show how to work around such basic capabilities of the language, but to make you keep in mind that this workaround is very not comfortable :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how well does this handle repetitions in data — say 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 as the set of five values?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler very badly :( I'll fix that